# Why aren't those two expressions equivalent and one gives an error?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

```
--Find kth element of list
elementAt :: (Int b) => [a] -> b -> a
elementAt a b = case a of [] -> error "Empty List"
                          a -> if (length a) <= b && b>=1 then a !! (b- 1) else error "Wrong index"
```

Gives an error `Expected kind -> constraint but Int has kind *`.

Compared to:

```
elementAt :: [a] -> Int -> a
elementAt a b = case a of [] -> error "Empty List"
                          a -> if (length a) <= b && b>=1 then a !! (b- 1) else error "Wrong index"
```

Which doesn't give an error.
Why is that ?

Comment: `Int b` isn't a valid constraint, because `Int` is a type, not a type class.

Comment: A `C a =>` does *not* mean that `a` is the `C` type, it means that `a` is an *instance* of the `C` *typeclass*. You can see typeclasses as a "group of types" that all implement a collection of functions (this is an oversimplification however).

Answer (score 5):

`Int` is a type, not a type class, so `Int b` is not a valid constraint. What constraint *do* you need on `b`?

1. You use `b` with both `<=` and `>=`, so `b` has to have an `Ord` constraint.
2. You use `b - 1`, so `b` has to have a `Num` constraint.

However, since `b-1` is the second argument to `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`, you don't really have any leeway in what type `b` can be: `b - 1` has to be an `Int`, and so does `b`. Thus, the type should simply be

```
elementAt ::  [a] -> Int -> a
```

Since `Int` has both `Num` and `Ord` instances, the requirements listed above are satisfied.

Comment: A good way to discover this sort of thing is to just remove the type annotation and then inspect the inferred type.

Comment: Thanks this helps!